# StdAfx + Header file - Order of inclusion in MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, compiler-errors, stdafx.h

I am using Visual Studio 2005. I created an MFC based console application named "StdAfx dependancy". The IDE created the following files for me.

1. Resource.h
2. StdAfx Dependancy.h
3. stdafx.h
4. StdAfx Dependancy.cpp
5. stdafx.cpp

I added another class `CHelper` with Helper.h and Helper.cpp as below.

Helper.h:

```
#pragma once

class CHelper
{
public:
    CHelper(void);
    ~CHelper(void);
};
```

Helper.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "Helper.h"

CHelper::CHelper(void)
{
}

CHelper::~CHelper(void)
{
}
```

I created an object for `CHelper` in the main function; to achieve this I added Header.h file in the first line of StdAfx Dependancy.cpp as below; and I got the following errors.

> d:\codes\stdafx dependancy\stdafx
>   dependancy\stdafx dependancy.cpp(33) :
>   error C2065: 'CHelper' : undeclared
>   identifier
>   d:\codes\stdafx
>   dependancy\stdafx dependancy\stdafx
>   dependancy.cpp(33) : error C2146:
>   syntax error : missing ';' before
>   identifier 'myHelper'
>   d:\codes\stdafx
>   dependancy\stdafx dependancy\stdafx
>   dependancy.cpp(33) : error C2065:
>   'myHelper' : undeclared identifier

But when I include it after `stdafx.h`, the error vanishes. Why?

```
// Stdafx dependancy.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "Helper.h"

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Stdafx dependancy.h"

// #include "Helper.h" --> If I include it here, there is no compilation error

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
    if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        CHelper myHelper;
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This link must give you some clue.
[Purpose of stdafx.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976035/purpose-of-stdafx-h)

The lines defined before the
 `#include "stdafx.h"` are ignored by the compiler. So if you want to actually include those files then you need to include them after the `#include "stdafx.h".`

Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ckv's answer, it makes little sense to include header files before "stdafx.h" as any non-trivial header file will contain framework types that are included there (e.g. any MFC types).