# % versus FMOD for calculating modulus

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, console-application

My console app looks like that.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a, b;
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"% "<<a%b<<endl<<"fmod "<<fmod(a,b)<<endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I'm newbie to C++ and I got 2 questions:

1. Writing this application on VS. Why do I need to include "stdafx.h"? Is there any requirement? What is this?
2. Is there any difference between `fmod` and `%` ? Getting exactly same results for them:

[image]

Thx in advance..

Comment: Your first question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976035/purpose-of-stdafx-h

Comment: Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Writing this application on VS. Why do I need to include "stdafx.h"? Is there any requirement? What is this?

Because the default project setting says you need precompiled header (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976035/purpose-of-stdafx-h)).

You can disable this manually. Select **Not Using Precompiled Headers** as shown in the image below:

[image]

---

> Is there any difference between fmod and % ? Getting exactly same results for them:

Yes. `%` cannot operate on floating-pointer numbers, while `fmod` can. `f` in [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) indicates floating-point.

Try this:

```
float a, b;
std::cin>>a>>b;
std::cout << (a%b) << std::endl; //it will give compilation error.
```

Answer (score 1):

fmod( a , b ) will cast the int variables a and b to floats when the parameters are passed. Depending on the type of a and b (for instance, if you use std::uint64_t) you might lose precision during the cast and get something incorrect returned. The return type will also be a float and will need to be cast again if you're using the function with int types. You should stick to % for int types. Using fmod is less efficient.