# Why stdfax.h should be the first include on MFC applications?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I want to know why this line exists on every MFC app (which force to make stdafx.h the first header included in every file) :

```
#ifndef __AFXWIN_H__
    #error "include 'stdafx.h' before including this file for PCH"
#endif
```

What are the reason(s) behind this behavior ?

Comment: Note that PCH stands on _Pre Compiled Header_, which helps compiler to reduce the compile time.

Comment: Precompiled headers can only be used when the same headers are being included as the very first.

Comment: @sehe : more like a duplication of this one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976035/purpose-of-stdafx-h)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only true when using  Precompiled Headers (PCH), and the reason why there shouldn't be anything before the `#include "stdafx.h"`  is :

> **Visual C++ will not compile anything before the #include "stdafx.h"** in
>   the source file, unless the compile option /Yu'stdafx.h' is unchecked
>   (by default); it assumes all code in the source up to and including
>   that line is already compiled

from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header

Comment: thanks, MSDN.com wasn't really helpful on this matter ...

Answer (score 2):

You should read this brief description [`stdafx.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header#stdafx.h)

> Compatible compilers (for example, Visual C++ 6.0 and newer) will
>   precompile this file to reduce overall compile times. Visual C++ will
>   not compile anything before the #include "stdafx.h" in the source
>   file, unless the compile option /Yu'stdafx.h' is unchecked (by
>   default); it assumes all code in the source up to and including that
>   line is already compiled.

It implicitly says, to achieve advantages of PCH, you have to include `stdafx.h` as soon as possible in inclusion hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

`stdafx.h` file includes common headers those are used along different files in a project. It's not a must to include it but then you have to manage all the headers along your project and this will cause to repeat some headers along different files.