# Why I am getting this error in c++ code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stl, precompiled-headers

I have this simple code:

```
std::ifstream ifs;
ifs.open ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);
char c = ifs.get();
while (ifs.good()) {
   std::cout << c;
   c = ifs.get();
}
ifs.close();
```

But I am getting a lot of error?
such as:

```
Error   9   error C3083: 'ifstream': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type    test.cpp    
Error   8   error C2228: left of '.open' must have class/struct/union   test.cpp
```

and so on.

I have these definitions at the start of file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
```

I am using VS2012 on a console application.

edit1:

The complete code is as follow:

```
void ReadRawImages::Read(int frameNumber)
{
std::ifstream ifs;

      ifs.open ("test.txt", std::ifstream::in);

       char c = ifs.get();

       while (ifs.good()) {
            std::cout << c;
            c = ifs.get();
       }

  ifs.close();


 }
```

I also noted that I have these warnings:

```
Warning 1   warning C4627: '#include <iostream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use   test.cpp
Warning 2   warning C4627: '#include <fstream>': skipped when looking for precompiled header use    test.cpp
```

Comment: Can you post the code immediately before `std::ifstream ifs;`? Possibly you missed a semicolon somewhere earlier.

Comment: ditch the line "using namespace std" as you use std:: comprehensively

Comment: [Your code works fine](http://eval.in/31344). Did you wrap that code in a function at all?

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Thanks, I am sure that codes is correct, the problem is I am not sure that my setup is correct. What should I do to run this code in MS Visual C++ 2012?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put header files after  `#include "stdafx.h"`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

`stdafx.h` must be the first included file, this is Microsoft specific rule.

> Visual C++ will not compile anything before the #include "stdafx.h" in
>   the source file, unless the compile option /Yu'stdafx.h' is unchecked
>   (by default) [<sup>1</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header#stdafx.h)

Comment: Oh, I already answered same question before, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16040876/952747).

Answer (score 2):

Your project is probably making use of precompiled headers. If so, the first line of each `.cpp` file should be:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Or whatever the name of the header is.