# Scope of #define without a token-string in in C/C++

Tags: c-preprocessor

I have the following files:

**Main.c**

```
#include "Header.h"

#define SECRET_NUMBER_ENABLED

int main()
{
    printf("Secret number = %d\n", SECRET_NUMBER);
    return 0;
}
```

**Header.h**

```
#ifdef SECRET_NUMBER_ENABLED
    #define SECRET_NUMBER 111
#else
    #define SECRET_NUMBER 222
#endif
```

The print result is: 222

To my understanding, the Pre-Processor should scan Main.c and replace every SECRET_NUMBER with its defined number from Header.h,

And because SECRET_NUMBER_ENABLED is defined in Main.c, the Pre-processor should take the 111 definition instead of the 222.

Apparently I'm wrong, but I don't know why, and don't know how to set it correctly so only C files which have #define SECRET_NUMBER_ENABLED will use SECRET_NUMBER 111

Comment: did you try to put `#define SECRET_NUMBER_ENABLED` before the `#include` ?

Comment: Yes, same results, altough I am getting compilation warning: warning C4603: 'SECRET_NUMBER_ENABLED' : macro is not defined or definition is different after precompiled header use

Comment: My full code had the following includes: 
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Header.h"
when I put the define between them it works, when I put the define before the 2 includes i Get the warning above, and it doesn't work, can you explain why?

Comment: I have an stupid comment, but how knows... 
Did you check assigning a different name to the define `SECRET_NUMBER_ENABLED`?  Maybe there is a define with that name in the stdafx.h or its dependences

Comment: Yes, I checked a different name, still doesn't work.

Comment: Including stdafx.h messes with already defined macros. Only macros defined afterwards are safe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040689/why-stdfax-h-should-be-the-first-include-on-mfc-applications

Answer (score 1):

Anything before including "stdafx.h" is assumed to have already been defined.
See [Why stdfax.h should be the first include on MFC applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040689/why-stdfax-h-should-be-the-first-include-on-mfc-applications)

So any earlier definition gets lost.

That is why you need to define your macros

- after including stdafx.h
  (because otherwise they get ignored)
- before including your own header
  (because otherwise they wont have an effect on your header,
  the #ifdef inside your header is evaluated before the definition in main.c is seen)