# Namespace declared in Header file is not being recognized in Source File

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header, namespaces, stdafx.h

What am i doing wrong here?

**APP.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace App{

    enum class AppStatus{
    Exit,
    Menu,
    Run
    };

    void frameLoop();

    AppStatus state;

}
```

**App.cpp**

```
#include "App.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Graphic\Graphic.h>


void App::frameLoop()
{
    while (state != AppStatus::Exit) {

        Graphic::renderingSequence();
    }
}
```

**Errors**

```
Error   C2653   'App': is not a class or namespace name App 
Error   C2065   'state': undeclared identifier  App 
Error   C2653   'AppStatus': is not a class or namespace name   App 
Error   C2065   'Exit': undeclared identifier   App
```

Note that my namespace `Graphic` (declared in \Graphic\Graphic.h) is being recognized by the compiler, even though i declared it just the same way.

Comment: `#include "stdafx.h"` Must always be the first non comment line. All lines above that are ignored by the compiler.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks! will have to learn more about what exactly is special about `#include <stdafx.h>`

Comment: @drescherjm I did not find anything that helped me, because i did not expect that #include can have variable functionality

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040689/why-stdfax-h-should-be-the-first-include-on-mfc-applications

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2976046/487892

Comment: + for direction

Comment: @stimulate If you are clear now, please click on the big green check mark below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stdafx.h (Microsoft precompiled header) must be at the top. This applies to any Visual C++ project with the precompiled headers option turned on, and stdafx.h the standard pch. Those are the default settings for a new project.

[Purpose of stdafx.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976035/purpose-of-stdafx-h)

The simplest and least error-prone way to define the function within the namespace App is just to 
put it there.

**APP.CPP**

```
#include "stdafx.h" // Nothing goes above this
#include "App.h"
#include <Graphic\Graphic.h>

namespace App {
    void frameLoop()
    {
        while (state != AppStatus::Exit) {
            Graphic::renderingSequence();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with Jive you should put the function in the namespace rather than saying App::frameLoop(). It might be confusing for people and they might think App is a class.

Comment: More importantly, the code in the cpp file will automatically resolve names the same as the .h file does. E.g. AppStatus::Exit.