# Error C2062: type unexpected when referencing std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

namespace myNamespace
{
    struct MyStruct
    {
        static std::map<int, std::string> idNameMap;
        // some other static properties
    };

    class MyClass
    {
    private:
        void myMethod() {
            std::map<int, std::string>& myMap = MyStruct::idNameMap; // C2062: type 'int' unexpected

            for (auto& it : myMap)
            {
                // do some stuff with map values
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I'm trying to reference the static map property in `MyStruct` but it is producing this error. I'm not sure if more context is needed, but if so please let me know.

Comment: Have you #included <map> and <string>, right?

Comment: @roalz: I do yes. Will add that in for clarification

Comment: You should edit your question to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is `MyStruct` in the same header as `MyClass`. So we can assume there is no circular include path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ initialize static variables in class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019856/c-initialize-static-variables-in-class)

Comment: What compiler are you using? I cannot reproduce the error with msvc 18.00 or gcc 6.1

Comment: @drescherjm: Yeah, same header file

Comment: @MadScientist: msvc 19.00

Comment: Could it be related to the static variables not being initialized properly?

Comment: ***Could it be related to the static variables not being initialized properly?*** No

Comment: @sookie: either you are not using vs 2015 (vc140, aka msvc 19.00, just tested, compiles this code fine), or you are not compiling the same code you posted. Other possible causes may include evil re-definition of types (typedefs or #defines anywhere?)

Comment: I just compiled this code in Visual Studio 2015 without any issue at all. I mean after adding a main and defining idNameMap (since this is not a complete example).

Comment: @drescherjm: Right, thanks for taking the time out to help. I'd say a different error is propagating other errors (producing this one)

Comment: @sookie: Is "C2062: type 'int' unexpected" the exact error message you get?

Comment: You can easily copy the text of the error message from the Output Tab of Visual Studio after you build.

Comment: @roalz: Yes, along with 100+ other errors (mostly syntax errors which don't seem to point to anything out of the ordinary)

Comment: See my answer, it should help you in spotting the root cause of the error, hopefully..

Comment: @roalz: Yep see it, looking through my code now

Comment: My advice is to look at the errors in the order that they appear in your source code. Solve the first error first. I find it easier to look at this in the Output Tab.

Comment: @drescherjm: First one is C2062. I usually follow the errors from top to bottom

Answer (score 0):

Let's try again...

You probably have an incorrectly terminated definition somewhere in your code, just before an int variable, that is not included in your question.

I.e. with this addition to your posted code, you will get exactly the same compiler error:

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

double x = 42.0, // ERROR! incorrectly terminated before an 'int' variable
int a = 0;

namespace myNamespace
{
...
```

Comment: Ok, well there is no variable declaration terminating with a comma

Comment: It may not be a comma, this is one of the possible causes, but it should be right before an 'int'.

Comment: Looks like including stdafx.h after including cpp's header file may have caused the issue

Comment: I tried to move the #include, but it still compiles fine, at least with a basic auto-made stdafx.h (Win32 console project template). Maybe it's something you include or define in your stdafx.h file... or the other way around, something in your header files messes up stdafx.h stuff.

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm also using win32 console application, with no modifications to stdafx.h. I assume this isn't an MFC application, as mentioned in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040689/why-stdfax-h-should-be-the-first-include-on-mfc-applications

Comment: What if you remove #include "stdafx.h" (and disable pre-compiled headers)?

Comment: I get the same result as when I'm using precompiled headers and ensuring "stdafx.h" is #included first. So ~100 errors seem to have been fixed, including error C2062. The problem with my OP was that I put the function definition in the .h for simplicity sake so you wouldn't have likely come to that conclusion. All-in-all my guess is that with MyClass.h being included before stdafx, it was assumed that it was already compiled, and it was skipped. This must've caused the compiler to not be able to see the declaration for myMap.