# PImpl with C++: Why does the code not work?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I've solved the problem by putting `#include "stdafx.h"` (this statement is missed in the original question, sorry for that) BEFORE `#include "PImplTest.h"` instead of AFTER it.

But I'm still confused why it cannot stay after it.

```
// stdafx.h
#include <tinyxml2.h>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <stack>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <assert.h>
```

----------------------- the original question --------------------------------

I'm trying to use the PImpl pattern in C++. The header file is:

```
// PImplTest.h

#pragma once
#include <memory>

class PImpl
{
private:
    class Impl;
    std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};
```

What confuses me is, if I implement the `Impl` class in the corresponding cpp file of the header like this:

```
// PImplTest.cpp
#include "PImplTest.h"
#include "stdafx.h" // this statement was missed in my first post

class PImpl::Impl // error C2079 'Impl' uses undefined class 'PImpl'
{ // error C2653 'PImpl':is not a class or namespace name
};
```

```
// main.cpp
#include "stdafx.h" // this statement was missed in my first post
#include "PImplTest.h"

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

VS reports the 2 errors in the code comments above. However, if it is implemented in a file like this:

```
// main.cpp
#include "PImplTest.h"

class PImpl::Impl
{ 
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Then nothing goes wrong.

What's the problem? How to fix it?

Comment: Are those the *only* `#include` directives, and in particular do you have other headers that include or are included by `PImplTest.h`?

Comment: nope, these are all the code

Comment: Heads up: you will need to add `~Pimpl();` in your header and `Pimpl::~Pimpl() = default;` in your cpp file so that `std::unique_ptr`'s destructor is instantiated when `Impl` is complete.

Comment: Is the error message that you quote the _first_ error message output by the compiler?

Comment: I'm very sorry for missing a line of code AFTER "#include"PImplTest.h"" in the file of PImplTest.cpp in the first case, that is "#include"stdafx.h"". When I put it BEFORE the include statement of PImplTest.h, everything is right. But I'm still confused, why the include of pch should stay before the include of PImplTest.h?

Comment: Irene, the errors indicate the compiler doesn't actually see the header; if it's access the wrong file etc. Try placing the contents of the header inside the .cpp file and see what happens then. And - maybe post a self-contained program which fails to compile.

Comment: @Irene See [Why stdfax.h should be the first include on MFC applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040689/why-stdfax-h-should-be-the-first-include-on-mfc-applications) Voting to close as a duplicate.