# Error Identifier "Free" not found?

Tags: c, free

I am writing the following code on visual studio 2013

```
#include "malloc.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <assert.h>

void deltree(Node * n)
{
    if (n)
    {
        deltree(n->left);
        deltree(n->right);
        free(n);

    }
}
```

it doesnt work and it says "error C3861: 'free': identifier not found" any idea?

Comment: Could you show us your malloc.h ? Do you have any other definition of free somewhere ?

Comment: Either remove that [`"stdafx.h"` weirdness](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976035), or include it before anything else. Apparently, the compiler ignores anything before that (including your inclusion of `<stdlib.h>`, hence the error).

Comment: It seems to be C and not C++.  THe tags should be adjusted.

Comment: Choose your language, C or C++.  For c++ you should use `new` and `delete`, while they don't exist in the C language.

Comment: Your title says `Free`, but the code in the question says `free`. Which is it? (They're two distinct identifiers.) BTW, you don't need `"malloc.h"`; both `malloc` and `free` are declared in `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Where, I wonder, is `Node` defined?  Presumably, it must either be `malloc.c` or `stdafx.h` since none of the other headers normally defines it.