# Microsoft Visual Studio 17 errors compiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

Hello I have been having problems compiling and running my program. I just recently switched over from code::block to microsoft visual 2017.

The Error: Unable to start program 'c:\users\myname\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Debug\ConsolApplication1.exe' The system cannot find the file specified.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello";
    return 0;
}
```

The Consol:

1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication1.cpp
1>c:\users\myname\documents\visual studio 2017\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1.cpp(13): error C2065: 'cout': undeclared identifier
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reasons I am not privy to, the compiler in Visual Studio ignores anything above the include of stdafx.h.

Solution: Reorder the includes to place `#include "stdafx.h"` at the top.

Alternate Solution: Remove `#include "stdafx.h"` and [disable precompiled headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hy7a92h.aspx).

The following may be helpful reading: [Purpose of stdafx.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976035/purpose-of-stdafx-h)

Comment: Thank you very much. That helps a lot.