# How to select parts of sentences in strings (C++)

Tags: c++, string, shell, command-line, command

I am making a command line program, and I was wondering how to get different parts of sentences, so lets say if someone entered `cd Windows/Cursors`, it would detect (with an if statement) that they entered `cd` and then (in that same if statement) it would select the rest of the sentence, and set that as the directory. This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        string directory = "C:/";
        string promptInput;
        string afterPrint;
        string prompt = "| " + directory + " |> ";
        cout << prompt;
        cin >> promptInput;

        if (promptInput == "") 
        {

        }
        else if (promptInput == "h:/")
        {
            directory = "H:/";
        }
        if (promptInput != "") {
            cout << "    " << afterPrint << "\n";
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't tried anything yet, so I am open to suggestions.

Help will be highly appreciated.

-*Caleb Sim*

Comment: Unrelated: if you are using Visual Studio, and `#include "stdafx.h"` suggests this, put `#include "stdafx.h"` at the first thing in the file. Everything above it will be ignored. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976035/purpose-of-stdafx-h. Why people put up with this smurf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726155/whats-the-use-for-stdafx-h-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::stringstream` to read each line and convert it to stream. Then break the line in to separate parts, create a response based on the first word in the line. For example:

```
#include <sstream>
...
int main()
{
    string line;
    while(getline(cin, line))
    {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string cmd;
        if(ss >> cmd)
        {
            if(cmd == "cd")
            {
                string dir;
                if(ss >> dir)
                {
                    cout << "changedir: " << dir << "\n";
                }
            }
            else if(cmd == "c:" || cmd == "c:\\")
            {
                cout << "changedir: " << cmd << "\n";
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "error\n";
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer depends on your problem set, but a specific answer for your example could look as follows:

```
else if (promptInput == "cd")
{
     std::string directory;
     std::getline(std::cin, directory);
     ChangeDirectory(directory);
}
```